# БД для опросов mysql

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Необходимо реализовать БД для системы опросов. Должны быть следующие колонки: id опроса, название опроса, варианты ответа опроса, количество проголосовавших за тот или иной вариант ответа.
Как это можно реализовать? Буду благодарен хотя бы за идею

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Таблица "опросы" - содержит поля "id опроса" (primary key) и "название опроса".

Таблица "варианты ответов" - содержит поля "id варианта ответа" (primary key), "id опроса" и "вариант ответа".

Таблица "голоса" - содержит поля "id варианта ответа" и "количество голосов".

Связь между таблицами "опросы" и "варианты ответов" - один ко многим, а между таблицами "варианты ответов" и "голоса" - один к одному.